# Return the "position" data from getCurrentPosition. Phonegap,HTML5, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, geolocation

Ok sorry for all the logging Ive been trying to figure out how to return the whole object position. So I can access the items in it later on in the function I called the getCurrentPosition from. Here is a mock of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any help!

```
 function aFunctionName(){   
    pos = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, geoFail);
    cameraLat = pos.coords.latitude;
     \\cannot read property coords
     console.log(cameraLat);
    cameraLong = pos.coords.longitude;
     \\cannot read property coords
     console.log(cameraLong);
    cameraTimestamp = pos.timestamp;
     console.log(cameraTimestamp)
     \\Cant read property timestamp
}

function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    cameraLati = position.coords.latitude;
     console.log(cameraLati);
     \\works fine and displays the lat
    cameraLongi = position.coords.longitude;
     console.log(cameraLongi);
     \\works fine and displays the long
    cameraTimestampi = position.timestamp;
     console.log(cameraTimestampi);
     \\works fine and displays the timestamp
   return position;
}
function onGeofail() {
  console.log("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to **getCurrentLocation** isn't a synchronous operation so you won't be able to do what you're trying.  However, you're passing in a **onGeoSuccess** function and presumably getting a valid position back.  Can you not perform what you need to in that function (as you are doing, in fact)?

**[Update based on new info]**
Ok, so if you need to something with some extra variables in your success function then try the following:

```
function saveDataWithPosition(data1, data2, data3, etc.){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function (position) {   
                // Insert data
                // Here you'll have access to your data params
                // and the position obj
            }, function (error) {               
                // Handle the error how you wish
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I hope that helps, and more importantly, I hope it works.

Comment: The problem is im trying to save those cords to use at a later time. Its for my mobile app im working on and I store the geo location and photo information inside of a database. the problem is due to unique key constraints that I need to enforce the insert statement is done all at once, I can't do an insert then an update, so i cant preform the action inside of that onGeoSuccess because I have no way of passing in my photo information for the database.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something, but why can't you make the insert from within your "success" function?

Comment: I need to pass the image data and a bunch of other informations thats already inside the "aFunctionName" function. Do you think I should just pass all that information(about 8 variables) to the onGeoSuccess function? navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8), geoFail); ?

Comment: You won't be able to do that.  I'll update my answer shortly.  It would be wise to update your question and include the details you've just told me about.

Comment: Thank you I will test and post if it worked as soon as I get home.